# Deploying with remote DB do I need to install it locally as-well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to deploy my app to the server, and I've skipped the step about installing postgres on the server, as I have a remote server that will handle my database.

I'm using capistrano and unicorn if that's relevant, and what I've done to try and configure it so that it'll understand that the database is remotely is to do:

```
production:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

where I've added the DATABASE_URL to the server, and the format is like this:

```
postgres://[username]:[password]@aws-eu-west-1-portal.0.dblayer.com:10155/db-table
```

thus being:

```
export DATABASE_URL="postgres://[username]:[password]@aws-eu-west-1-portal.0.dblayer.com:10155/DB-TABLE"
```

However when I run

```
bin/cap production deploy
```

I get:

```
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@ip-address: bundle exit status: 5
bundle stdout: An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.1'` succeeds before bundling.
bundle stderr: Nothing written
```

Also could it be because I installed a firewall that blocks most ports except these:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Any idea on how to get this working properly?

Comment: You still need the pg gem, though.

Comment: @DaveNewton ... and it requires a local `libpq`. It doesn't care about a PostgreSQL server, but it requires the client library.